# SDL2 OpenGL in Windowed Mode on Raspbian

Tags: opengl-es, raspberry-pi, sdl-2

Using a Raspberry Pi 2 I'd like use SDL 2 to create hardware accelerated OpenGL ES 2 programs in windowed mode. I'm currently unable to do this. I'd also like the ability to toggle between full screen and windowed mode in my programs if possible.

I believe my problem is related to the build configuration I am using from SDL2 sources.

I followed this guide to get SDL2 working with OpenGL ES from sources on my Raspberry, and it works for creating full screen SDL2 programs with an OpenGL ES context:

https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-getting-started-sdl-2/

The guide makers configure options are:

../configure --host=armv7l-raspberry-linux-gnueabihf --disable-pulseaudio --disable-esd --disable-video-mir --disable-video-wayland --disable-video-x11 --disable-video-opengl

In his guide, the creator states: "The above options will make sure, SDL 2 is built with the OpenGL ES backend and that any SDL application will run as a full screen application,"

I would really like to modify the build configuration to allow for windowed mode. What options would I need to change in his configure to allow for OpenGL ES 2 in windowed mode which can be toggled to full screen?

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowFullscreen

That is, to have the option to create a windowed SDL2 OpenGL ES program at first, with the option to toggle between full screen and windowed from within my program. How can I make an SDL2 for Raspbian to allow for this kind of behaviour?

My system details:

Raspberry Pi 2
Raspbian OS 
LXDE desktop

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `--disable-video-x11` option you're passing to the `./configure` script. X11 is the window manager and is responsible for creating your windows.

It appears this is typically not recommended since it can cause somewhat buggy behaviour.

For copy paste lovers

```
./configure --host=armv7l-raspberry-linux-gnueabihf --disable-pulseaudio --disable-esd --disable-video-mir --disable-video-wayland  --disable-video-opengl
```

Comment: Is not the problem that, with X11 enabled, SDL will generate OpenGL code, which is emulated in software on the GLES Pi?